Rename output files based on directory name
I'm migrating my multisite Laravel app from Mix to Vite. With Mix I was renaming assets based on directory name. Is it possible with Vite?
My Mix code:
const { readdirSync, statSync } = require("fs");
const { join } = require("path");

const dirs = (p) =>
  readdirSync(p).filter(
    (f) => statSync(join(p, f)).isDirectory();
  );

let brands = dirs("./brands");

brands.forEach((brand) => {
    mix.js(
      `brands/${brand}/resources/scripts/app.js`,
      `public/scripts/${brand}.js`
    ).vue();

    mix.sass(
      `brands/${brand}/resources/styles/app.scss`,
      `public/styles/${brand}.css`
    );
});


You can achieve this in Vite by dynamically configuring its entry points based on your directory structure.Vite allows customization through its vite.config.js file, where you can programmatically set up input files for the build.
Steps to follow:

Install Dependencies
Ensure you have Vite and any required plugins installed, such as @vitejs/plugin-vue for Vue support.
npm install vite @vitejs/plugin-vue

Create the Dynamic Input Script
Update your vite.config.js to dynamically configure inputs for the build.rollupOptions.input field, similar to how you did with Mix.

Dynamic Directory Parsing in Vite
Here's how you can configure Vite to handle the renaming logic based on directories:
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { readdirSync, statSync } from 'fs';
import { join, resolve } from 'path';

// Helper function to get directories
const dirs = (path) =>
  readdirSync(path).filter((file) => statSync(join(path, file)).isDirectory());

// Get all brand directories
const brands = dirs('./brands');

// Build the input object for Vite
const input = brands.reduce((entries, brand) => {
  entries[`scripts/${brand}`] = resolve(__dirname, `brands/${brand}/resources/scripts/app.js`);
  entries[`styles/${brand}`] = resolve(__dirname, `brands/${brand}/resources/styles/app.scss`);
  return entries;
}, {});

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input, // Dynamically generated inputs
      output: {
        entryFileNames: 'scripts/[name].js',
        assetFileNames: 'styles/[name].css',
      },
    },
  },
});





Key Details



dirs Function: Reads directories to identify brand-specific folders.

input Object: Maps each brand's app.js and app.scss as input files for Rollup (used by Vite under the hood).

Custom Output Naming: Use entryFileNames and assetFileNames in rollupOptions.output to control the output file structure.



Build the Project
Run the Vite build command to generate the assets.
npm run build


